# ws:// in a C program

Tags: c, sockets

I have a program that is running as a listener on a socket.  From a javascript page I am able to send an open socket request using Websocket (ws://).  My issue lies in that I can't seem to see the handshake or reply to it from the C program.  I used wireshark to confirm that the javascript is sending the correct handshake but when I try to receive it in the buffer all I get are zeros.

In addition I was able to test the javascript on ws://echo.websocket.org so I am pretty sure it is working correctly.  The error I get from the console in my web browser indicates that no reply was received to the handshake.

**Edit**: I know this is because I don't have a response set up.

My **updated** C program is as follows

```
#include <sys/socket.h> //for socket
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h> //strlen
#include <sys/types.h>

/* main function */
int main() {
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    int status;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char revcBuff[1025];
    int dataPresent = 0;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr)); //clear the memory for the server_addr
    memset(&revcBuff, 0, sizeof(revcBuff)); //clear the memory for the buffer
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //specifiys that the address is IPv4
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);//gets the local address
    //serv_addr.sin_port = htons(13669); //gets the local port
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); //gets the local port

    //designate the socket
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if(listenfd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket creation failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno )); //If the socket creation fails get the error
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //binds to the local address and port to listen
    while ( (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)))< 0) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "bind failed due to: %s\n Retrying.....\n", strerror( errno )); //If the bind fails get the error
        sleep(3); //time in seconds till next try
    } 

    //listen on socket
    if ( (listen(listenfd, 10))< 0) { 
       fprintf(stderr, "listen failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno ));//If the listen fails get the error
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //main program loop
    fprintf(stderr, "serverSock0-14 now running in listen mode \n");
    while (connfd >= 0) { //while socket is not in error mode try to accept incoming socket requests
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); //wait for an incoming socket request
        if ( connfd == -1) { //if atempted socket request failed 
            fprintf(stderr, "accept failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno )); // if the accept fails
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "connection opened \n");
        while (dataPresent != -1) { //keep socket open till you receive a packet
            dataPresent = recv(connfd, &revcBuff, sizeof revcBuff, MSG_TRUNC); //receive data from buffer
            //dataPresent = recv(connfd, revcBuff, sizeof revcBuff, MSG_DONTWAIT); //receive data from buffer
            if ( dataPresent == -1) { //test if new data is bad
                fprintf(stderr, "Receive failed due to: %s\n", strerror( errno )); // if the accept fails
            } else if ( dataPresent == 0) { // if the socket is closed on the other end
                break; // Escape to the close socket statement
            } else {
                revcBuff[dataPresent] = '\0'; // null terminate the buffer
                fprintf(stdout, "Buff Hex unsigned: %x %x %x \n", (unsigned int) revcBuff[0], (unsigned int) revcBuff[1], (unsigned int) revcBuff[2]); 
                fprintf(stdout, "Buff Hex: %x %x %x %x %x \n", revcBuff[0], revcBuff[1], revcBuff[2], revcBuff[3], revcBuff[4], revcBuff[5]); 
                fprintf(stdout, "Buff: %s \nbytes received: %i \n", revcBuff, dataPresent); //Print out what you received
            }
            dataPresent = 0;
            usleep(7000);
        }
        if ((close(connfd))==0){//close the socket
            fprintf(stdout, "connection closed\n");
        }
    } //end main program loop
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any direction would be super helpful.  I am still very new to the world of C.

Comment: You need a C websocket library.

Comment: Shouldn't the memset()s use 0 instead of '0' (which is 48)?

Comment: The whole memset() is cargo cult programming. instead the return from recv() should be used. (and: why would anyone use a RAW socket for this kind of trivial stuff?)

Comment: You need to receive on `connfd`, not `listenfd`. You also want `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)`. And `0` instead of `'0'`

Comment: Ok I updated the code in my question as those were some good changes.  Still having the same overall issue though.  In relation to David's comment.  Is there a standard websocket library?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard"? There's libwebsockets, which seems both stable and popular.

Comment: Yeah I just found that.  I have never used a library like this before so I will have to figure it out.  Thanks for the help guys.  I will update this when I get it working.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a library. You can write it yourself. A mistake that is pretty clear in your code is that 1. You never check if `recv()` returned an error value, 2. You don't guarantee that `sendBuf` is nul terminated. You can check that first. The handshake is relatively simple to code, and the [RFC 6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) has all the needed information, I find it very simple so instead of using a library you can indeed write this yourself.

Comment: Also, you have to be very careful if you are going to use *wss://* connections, in that case simplicity will be masked by the fact that you need to write the SSL too and it would be more logical to use some well tested tool no matter how hard it could be to learn how to use it, it is likely that writing it with SSL would be harder. I have some code I can share if you want. Just leave your e-mail.

Comment: Finally, [this could be easier than a library](http://websocketd.com/). Try it too, there's a very simple concept behind it.

Comment: when calling the system functions: `socket`, `listen`, `recv`, always check the returned value, as those kinds of functions are prone to having failures.   When calling `listen()`  it is (almost) always better to fork() or pthread_create() a separated line of execution to handle the incoming call, so can immediately loop back to the `accept()` function call.

Comment: when handling an error indication from a system function, printing some generic message is nearly useless.   Instead use something like: `fprintf( stderr, "bind failed: due to: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );

Comment: in C, a reference to an array name degrades to the address of the array.  `sendBuff[]` is just such an array.  so in the call to `recv()`, the parameter: `(char*)sendBuff` does not need a cast.  suggest: `sendBuff`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as pointed out by someone else, you should be using `connfd` in the `recv()` call:

```
recv(connfd, (char*)sendBuff, sizeof sendBuff, MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

If you have a `telnet` client available that can connect to your program, you should use that to experiment with your code.  For example, if you are running on Linux, start your program in one terminal window and, from another terminal, type

```
telnet localhost 5000
```

Here is what happens when I do it:

```
## The terminal where I run the program (a.out):
$ ./a.out 
connection opened 
Buff:  
connection closed
connection opened 
Buff:  
connection closed

## The terminal window I connect from:

$ telnet localhost 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
$ telnet localhost 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

See what's happening? And this is not surprising: the code accepts a connection from the client, tries to read a message from the client without giving it a chance to send it, gets nothing (of course!), doesn't ever send anything back to the client, and closes the connection.  Then it waits for the next connection.

Please read some tutorials on C socket programming, play with it, get it to work with a telnet client, and then move on to websockets.

It's a good start, anyway.  Good luck!

Comment: Good catch on the connfd.  I forgot to update that in the question.  I will play with getting the telnet to work in addition to my reading on libwebsockets.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider, instead of handling manually all the websocket details, to use some existing HTTP server library.

In particular, the [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) is a free software HTTP server library and it already supports websockets. See its [`examples/websockets/websockets.c`](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/blob/master/examples/websockets/websockets.c) file